# Op Amp different supply voltage than signal voltage

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

I need to setup a differential op amp.  The question I have is if the source signals (from the sensor) can have a differnt power supply than that powering the op-amp.  The op amp will be sent to a microcontroller that will have different power requirements then the sensory.  Let me know if you need more follow up info.

Thanks as always!

Comment: This not an unusual case.  What you need to be concerned about is if the signal range excursion is outside of the input range of your op-amp's and also the impact of interference pickup and noise etc.  amongst other details.  need more info?  an emphatic YES! signal outout range, distance away, etc. etc.  as well a more succinct question.

Comment: The sensor is a strain gauge with its own power supply, I want to read the signal from a uController that has a higher voltage req.  The distance is about a foot.I can handle the noise issue, etc., but if the devices have different grounds, I think there may be an issue. The gauge has a lower voltage then the uController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have no problem as long as there is a return path from the op-amp circuit to the sensor circuit. Typically this return path is through the "ground" node:

[image]

As you suspect, if there is no common ground you will have problems. Even if you use a differential sensor signal to provide a return path, without a common ground, the sensor signal can easily drift out of the common mode input range of the op-amp.

Comment: I see what you are getting at.  Is there a way to create a ground node.  BTW, it took me a while to understand that ground in most electronics is synonymous with the negative battery terminal.   In the case of your diagram, there is a separate ground then the negative terms of the batteries. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @user1883691, in a schematic, if we draw a ground symbol like that, it's implied that all the nodes with that symbol are connected.